# How to write those expressions in coffee script?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to rewrite a javascript application to coffee script. Though, I can't find how to transform those 2 expressions (I added what I tried beneath). Can you help me please ?

```
var config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'configs'))[env];
(What I tried) : config = require path.join __dirname, 'configs'[env]

server.use(require('node-compass')({mode: 'expanded'}));
(What I tried) : server.use require 'node-compass (
    mode: 'expanded'
)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What about `config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'configs'))[env]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'configs'))[env]
server.use(require('node-compass') mode: 'expanded')
```

Comment: I though there would be a way to write it without the '(' and '['. Thanks for your answer